# Upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 failed with too many errors then the sytem failed to boot, can I fix it?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

After my i386 Ubuntu 14.04 VM upgraded to 16.04 without problems I decided to do the same with my x64 development VM too.

Downloading packages went fine but during install I got an error that a sysv related packages installer script exited with status 1. (I didn't noted the name unfortunately).

Then the installation proceeded and at a point it started spewing error boxes that many-many packages failed to configure. Then the entire installer bailed out without "too many errors."

When I rebooted the kernel panicked, I cannot boot with the 4.4.0 kernel installed, only the older ones. I managed to boot the system up with older kernel (with (upstart) suffix) and attempted to do a `dpkg --configure -a` but the confugrations of every package fails with:

```
insserv: Script virtuoso-nepomuk is broken: missing end of LSB comment
```

What can I do to get my system work again? Only a clean install helps now?
(after a couple of warnings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I share the solution I found to avoid headaches if someone again stumbles upon it:

What worked for me is simply moving the `virtuoso-nepomuk` script from `/etc/init.d`,

Then the `dpkg --reconfiugre -a` managed to configure most of the packages. Then after a reboot, an `apt-get install -f` followed by `dpkg --reconfigure -a`, fixed everything up.

I don't know what `virtuoso-nepomuk` is, but the removal of it didn't screwed up anything (yet).

Comment: For future problems - you *might* have obtained the same result by editing /etc/init.d/virtuoso-nepomuk and making sure that the blovk that starts with `### BEGIN INIT INFO` ends with `### END INIT INFO`.  Also, was this `dpkg --configure -a` rather than `dpkg --reconfigure -a`?

Answer (score 5):

I also faced this issue and filed a bug in launchpad : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sysvinit/+bug/1610241

My solution was the following :

- fix the /etc/init.d/virtuoso-nepomuk file by adding `### END INIT INFO` at the end of the block started with `### BEGIN INIT INFO`
- resume the upgrade process with `sudo apt-get upgrade`

In any case, it's a bug. I suggested a few ways to fix that on launchpad, but it's not done yet.

Comment: This worked for me!